# Finding delta if, then statement problem

Tags: calculus

I have no idea where to start with this problem. I have the graph drawn but do not know how to find delta.

> If $5<x<5 + \delta$ then $\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-5}} > 100$

Comment: Is the denominator of the fraction supposed to be $\sqrt{x}-5$ or $\sqrt{x-5}$?

Comment: √x-5 square root of x-5, all of it!

Answer (score 1):

For any $x>5$, we have that $\dfrac{\sqrt{x-5}}{100}$ is a positive number and we can safely multiply both sides of an inequality by it. Therefore,
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-5}}>100\iff \frac{x^2}{100}>\sqrt{x-5}.$$
(The $\iff$ arrow means *"the left side is true if and only if the right side is true"*. In other words, it indicates that they are equivalent statements.)

Given positive $a$ and $b$, we have $a>b\iff a^2>b^2$, so that (with $a=\dfrac{x^2}{100}$ and $b=\sqrt{x-5}$),
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-5}}>100\iff \frac{x^2}{100}>\sqrt{x-5}\iff \frac{x^4}{10000}>x-5.$$
For any $x>5$, we have
$$\frac{x^4}{10000}>\frac{5^4}{10000}=\frac{625}{10000}=0.0625.$$
Thus, as long as $x-5<0.0625$ - in other words, as long as $x<5+\delta$ where $\delta=0.0625$ - we get
$$\frac{x^4}{10000}>0.0625>x-5,$$
and we know (by our earlier work) that this means $x$ satisfies
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-5}}>100.$$
Thus, for all $5<x<5+\delta$ where $\delta=0.0625$, we have $\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-5}}>100$.

(Of course, any smaller $\delta>0$ will also work.)